# Angularjs - Using new scope or isolate scope: both approaches work but is one of them funky?

Tags: angularjs

I have coded two simple date picker directives that from an end user perspective function exactly the same. You can see how they work at http://jsbin.com/rapey/2/edit and http://jsbin.com/vuq/1/edit  The first which uses new scope is coded this way:

```
<div ng-controller='cntrl'>
   <br>
   Date in controller: {{date}}<br><br>
  <!-- <div date="date" datedirec ></div> -->
  <div date="date" datedirec ></div>
</div>

var myMod = angular.module('app', []);

myMod.controller('cntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.date = '1/1/2000';
});

myMod.directive('datedirec', function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
//scope:{date:'='},
scope:true,
template: "<div>Date: <input type='text' ng-model='date_value'/>" +
"<button ng-click='updateDate()'>Update Date</button> </div>",
controller: function($scope, $element){
  $scope.date_value=$scope.date;
  $scope.updateDate = function(){
    //$scope.date=angular.copy($scope.date_value);
    $scope.$parent.date = angular.copy($scope.date_value);
  };
}
};
});
```

The second approach is coded exactly the same way as the first approach. But instead of using new scope it uses isolate scope.  There are only three small lines of difference between each example (see comments above).

Here is the first approach (it uses new scope in combination with  $scope.$parent): http://jsbin.com/rapey/2/edit

Here is the second approach (it uses isolate scope):  http://jsbin.com/vuq/1/edit

My question is whether one of these approaches shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer using an isolated scope whenever possible, as this creates loosely coupled components.  By using an isolated scope, you ensure that your directive continues to function even if the objects in other parts of the application change.  When using child scopes (`scope: true` creates a new scope that is a child of the parent), You are assuming that the parent component will always have a `date`.  If you happen to try to use your directive in a component where there is no `date` property, or the `date` property changes to `currentDate`, your directive will fail.

Comment: Another way to say it, don't depend on the environment, the parent component. Applies in plain JS/HTML too, if you're writing a JS component that manages/wraps a piece of HTML, it shouldn't depend on anything from its parent element if you want the component to be reusable.